# iCloud Photo Library and storage usage on devices

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, storage

Should you contemplate the utilization oF one of Apple's iCloud plans, it is of Utmost importance to grasp the intricacies of how it manages the storage of photos and videos on your device. From the information I have perused, it appears that upon activating this particular functionality, the photos and videos on your device undergo a transformative process, wherein they are converted into "lightweight versions" that occupy a reduced amount of storage space.

Allow me to paint a hypothetical picture for you: Suppose you possess a capacious 200 GB iCloud storage plan, of which approximately 190 GB has already been allocated for storing an extensive collection of photos. In light of this scenario, the question that arises is how your iPhone, which offers a meager 16 GB of storage capacity, will contend with this situation. Given the presumption that the available 16 GB is inadequate to accommodate the storage demands imposed by the "lightweight versions" of your photos, it begs the question whether your device will issue warnings pertaining to insufficient storage or similar notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a lightweight version it's more like a preview and then when you're connected to the internet you have access to the photo in full resolution. Your iPhone will let some space to the photos it will just optimise the storage, not all photos will be in the cloud. But I'm not sure if it can handle 200Gb but some space in your iPhone will be used depending on how frequently you access your photos in the cloud.